# AvalonEdit : Textstate

Tags: c#, .net, avalonedit

How to determine in Avalonedit, that text is modified? I want to notify user, that text modifications are saved / unsaved into the file.

I've tried such code, but `IsModified` property seams is set after `TextChanged` event occurred. So I always getting value of `IsModified` for previous modification step.

```
this.TextEditor.TextChanged += (o, i) =>
{
   this.CurrentStatus = this.TextEditor.IsModified ? Status.FILENOTSAVED : Status.NONE;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

`IsModified` is a dependency property. You should use WPF data binding to bind it to your `CurrentStatus` property instead of doing it manually.

Alternatively, use `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` to listen to dependency property changes:

```
var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(TextEditor.IsModifiedProperty, typeof(TextEditor));
dpd.AddValueChanged(this.TextEditor, OnIsModifiedChanged);
```

Don't forget to also use `RemoveValueChanged`, or you'll [leak memory](https://agsmith.wordpress.com/2008/04/07/propertydescriptor-addvaluechanged-alternative/).